# collationStringSelector error : Unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement alphabetical sections in my application to learn Swift.
I found this tutorial to help me : http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/04/uitableview-sectioning-and-indexing/

First, I separate the class from the UITableViewController class for more readability.

But I have an error on the collationStringCollector, it does not recognize "m_titre" and I do not understand how collationStringSelector works and so, how to use it.

```
var lesCours: [Cours] = cours_array.map { eachCours in // cours_array contain all "Cours" which will be indexed
        eachCours.section = self.collation.sectionForObject(eachCours, collationStringSelector: "title")
        return eachCours
    }
```

Here is my class "Cours"

```
class Cours {
var m_id : String
var m_titre : String
var m_content : String
var m_accept : Bool
var m_date : NSDate?
var section: Int?

init(titre:String, content:String)
{
    self.m_titre = titre
    self.m_content = content
    self.m_id = ""
    self.m_accept = false
    self.m_date = nil
}

// ... getters, setters, specifics function
```

Thank you

PS : I apologize if my English is not perfect, it's not my native language, I hope that you will understand without difficulty in despite of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors use Objective-C message passing, therefore the property must be
"Objective-C compatible". The easiest way to achieve this is to make your
class a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
class Cours : NSObject {
    // ...
}
```

And of course the selector must match the name of the property, in your
case "m_titre" instead of "title".